# Where do I suggest features for the CCSM replacement?

Tags: community, ccsm

There are a few features available in CCSM (compiz config settings manager) that I want to make sure are available even if CCSM becomes completely defunct and replaced in Ubuntu. And, I would like to help improve Ubuntu going forward. So, I'd just like to know where is the best place to makes these suggestions and offer insight into my Ubuntu desktop usage patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can propose your ideas in [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/).

You can take a look at the [Ubuntu Brainstorm tour](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/tour) to learn how to use the site.